# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "_cvHaarDetectObjects" Eclipse

Tags: opencv, face-detection, classification

I'm trying to build the following sample code:

```
#include "cv.h"
#include "highgui.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <float.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <ctype.h>


// Create a string that contains the exact cascade name
const char* cascade_name = "/usr/share/src/OpenCV-2.3.1/data/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml";
 //   "C:/Program Files/OpenCV/data/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml";
/*    "haarcascade_profileface.xml";*/


// Function prototype for detecting and drawing an object from an image
void detect_and_draw( IplImage* image );

// Main function, defines the entry point for the program.
int main( int argc, char** argv )
{

    // Create a sample image
    IplImage *img = cvLoadImage("1.pgm");

    // Call the function to detect and draw the face positions
    detect_and_draw(img);

    // Wait for user input before quitting the program
    cvWaitKey();

    // Release the image
    cvReleaseImage(&img);

    // Destroy the window previously created with filename: "result"
    cvDestroyWindow("result");

    // return 0 to indicate successfull execution of the program
    return 0;
}

// Function to detect and draw any faces that is present in an image
void detect_and_draw( IplImage* img )
{

    // Create memory for calculations
    static CvMemStorage* storage = 0;

    // Create a new Haar classifier
    static CvHaarClassifierCascade* cascade = 0;

    int scale = 1;

    // Create a new image based on the input image
    IplImage* temp = cvCreateImage( cvSize(img->width/scale,img->height/scale), 8, 3 );

    // Create two points to represent the face locations
    CvPoint pt1, pt2;
    int i;

    // Load the HaarClassifierCascade
    cascade = (CvHaarClassifierCascade*)cvLoad( cascade_name, 0, 0, 0 );

    // Check whether the cascade has loaded successfully. Else report and error and quit
    if( !cascade )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "ERROR: Could not load classifier cascade\n" );
        return;
    }

    // Allocate the memory storage
    storage = cvCreateMemStorage(0);

    // Create a new named window with title: result
    cvNamedWindow( "result", 1 );

    // Clear the memory storage which was used before
    cvClearMemStorage( storage );

    // Find whether the cascade is loaded, to find the faces. If yes, then:
    if( cascade )
    {

        // There can be more than one face in an image. So create a growable sequence of faces.
        // Detect the objects and store them in the sequence
        CvSeq* faces = cvHaarDetectObjects( img, cascade, storage,
                                            1.1, 2, CV_HAAR_DO_CANNY_PRUNING,
                                            cvSize(40, 40) );

        // Loop the number of faces found.
        for( i = 0; i < (faces ? faces->total : 0); i++ )
        {
           // Create a new rectangle for drawing the face
            CvRect* r = (CvRect*)cvGetSeqElem( faces, i );

            // Find the dimensions of the face,and scale it if necessary
            pt1.x = r->x*scale;
            pt2.x = (r->x+r->width)*scale;
            pt1.y = r->y*scale;
            pt2.y = (r->y+r->height)*scale;

            // Draw the rectangle in the input image
            cvRectangle( img, pt1, pt2, CV_RGB(255,0,0), 3, 8, 0 );
        }
    }

    // Show the image in the window named "result"
    cvShowImage( "result", img );

    // Release the temp image created.
    cvReleaseImage( &temp );
}
```

And the path /usr/share/src....is the right path where the xml file is. I've linked the opencv libraries: opencv_core, opencv_imgproc, opencv_highgui and opencv_video to eclipse (and I think they are correctly linked since I build other opencv projects in this way). But Eclipse keeps throwing the following errors:

```
Invoking: MacOS X C++ Linker
g++ -L/usr/local/include/opencv -L/usr/local/include/opencv2 -L/usr/local/lib -o "OpenCVFace"  ./main.o   -lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_video -lopencv_imgproc
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_cvHaarDetectObjects", referenced from:
      detect_and_draw(_IplImage*)     in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [OpenCVFace] Error 1

**** Build Finished ****
```

I can see the cvHaarDetectObjects function is highlighted in Eclipse (which turned to purple color). Any ideas of how to solve the problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to link to `opencv_objdetect`; include `-lopencv_objdetect` in the link flags.